# Is the image by a closed range operator of a closed subspace closed too?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and suppose we have a bounded closed range operator $T\in B(H)$.
Is $T(M)$ closed for every closed subspace $M\subset H$ ?

Thank you !

Comment: No! This is not even true if $T$ is an orthogonal projection. See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/163844/is-an-open-linear-map-closed-to-some-extent However, if the kernel is finite-dimensional (i.e., $T$ is upper semi-Fredholm), then the answer is always yes.

Comment: Thank you so much